# How to use *.vue components (SFC files) without vue cli

Tags: vue.js

I can’t figure out how to use *.vue components if I install vue with cdn
Is it possible?

I'm talking about [these template files](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html):

```js
<template>

</template>

<script>

</script>

<style scoped> 

</style>
```

I worked with cli it was easy
but when installing from cdn there are always errors with imports

Comment: You can't, that's the purpose of cli. .vue is custom format that was invented by vue team and not not spec compliant script that can be evaluated in a browser. You can use other build tool but there should be build step any way

Answer (score 0):

As written here: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html#why-sfc

> While SFCs require a build step [...]

A CDN will always have some limitations/issues overall. You could meanwhile probably bundle and run a Vue app on some already existing website.
Requires further consulting overall but you probably can't use SFC without some super hacky way.

Comment: So exactly the same as my answer? :p